# Cannot run bash on my windows 10 and linux subsystem on my Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

1. I have enabled "Windows Subsystem for Linux"
2. I have switched to "Developer mode"
   restarted my PC.
3. Downloaded a Linux system (Ubuntu) 
   I PowerShell -

   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804-lte -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing

   Add-AppxPackage .\Ubuntu.appx
4. Run Linux inside Windows 10  - **DOESN'T WORK**

When I run bash command from my console I get the following: 
[image]

It looks like that the bash and ubuntu is installed but doesn't work

[image]

[image]

**EDITED**:
I also get this error:
[image]

Comment: What is the output from: `wsl -l` on a command prompt?

Comment: @Luuk - Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions. Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store: https://aka.ms/wslstore

Comment: Go to that link (or start 'Microsoft Store'), and download/install Ubuntu...

Comment: Cannot use Microsoft Store - company restriction

Comment: Try: https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab  OR    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q?source=lp&activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: That link whants to open "Microsoft Store"

Comment: Than you have to contact the person who is dealing with your 'company restriction' .... 

Comment: You where following instruction from this place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual ?    it should work, but because of those 'company restrictions' it just might not work.... 

Comment: Some of my colleges installed it and it works for them. I followed exactly the same instructions.

Comment: After Invoke-Webrequest, you should write 'https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804' and not 'https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804-lte'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open an admin powershell terminal

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Reboot

Download a linux distrubution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

In a powershell terminal

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing
```

Move to desired location on system c:/_distros/ then rename and extract the binaries via powershell

```
Rename-Item Ubuntu.appx Ubuntu.zip
Expand-Archive Ubuntu.zip Ubuntu
```

Add your distro path to the Windows environment PATH (C:\Distros\Ubuntu in this example), e.g. using Powershell:

```
$userenv = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $userenv + "C:\_distros\Ubuntu", "User")
```

Run ubuntu.exe to install